# Replace a word in BLOB text by MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, replace, blob

I've got a huge mysql table (called `tcountriesnew`) and a column (called `slogen, blob type`).
In each of those `slogen` blobs I'd like to replace a word, for example: `banana` to `apple`.

Unfortunately I tried to print all the rows with word banana, and it did not work.

`select * from tcountriesnew where slogen like '%banana%';`

Please help me.

- What i missed, what is the problem with my query?
- How can i replace text in blob?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "replace"; using replace to show modified text in select:

```
select replace(slogen, 'bananas', 'apples') from tcountriesnew where slogen like '%bananas%';
```

Or update data in a table:

```
update tcountriesnew set slogen=replace(slogen, 'bananas', 'apples') where slogen like '%bananas%';
```

BTW. Why are you using `blob` for text? You should use `text` type for textual data and `blob` for binary data.

Comment: In some cases it is needed to save texts BLOB. In my case, for whatever reason Drupal 7 developers choose to use a blob for all TEXT columns - usually this is out developer's control.

Comment: If you want to support any all languages out there then `BLOB` might be needed. Maybe. For most languages `TEXT` is fine. You loose a lot functions when using `BLOB` as essentially the text is not seen as text server side. That's why I would recommend using `TEXT`. If there are still some problems with some languages then they will probably be fixed in MySQL server anyway.

Comment: @Nux: What if only one occurrence of bananas needs to be replaced instead of all lets say it is at position 2380 . How to do that

Comment: If it is at a know position then you could split the string with substr or something like that. Have a look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: @Nux: The problem is replace is updating all the occurrence even when the position is specified of the string . However when you use the same values for select query it displays updated value only at one occurrence

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `select replace('bananas are bananas', 'bananas', 'apples')` will output `apples are apples`. If you want single replacement then you need to find a different way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases it is needed to save texts BLOB. In my case, for whatever reason Drupal 7 developers choose to use a blob for all TEXT columns - this is out of developer's control.

To convert a blob to text, use the MySql convert function. Then you have to save it into the database and convert it again to blob - but this is handled automatically by MySQL. So the following query would do the trick:

```
UPDATE tcountriesnew 
SET slogen = replace(CONVERT(slogen USING utf8), 'bananas', 'apples')
WHERE slogen LIKE '%bananas%';
```

On MySQL 5.5, This resolved my issue completely.

Also, [configure your PhpMyAdmin to show Blob data](http://groups.drupal.org/node/134269)

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using ? Maybe it's this bug : http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27.
Otherwise try to [cast](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html) your blob column.